# How do i count based on the difference of value in 1 ID?

Tags: sql

I need to count the number of column A based on car ID.

Data as per below:

```
Car ID     A
BMW        BUY
BMW        BUY
BMW        SELL
AUDI       BUY
AUDI       SELL
AUDI       SELL
```

as per data below, i want to have a new column stating 2 for BMW BUY while 1 for BMW SELL. AUDI BUY 1 and AUDI SELL 2

I couldn't think of the SQL statement.

Comment: Look up "GROUP BY" and please tag your question with the database type you are using (there are usually differences in the exact SQL syntax)

Answer (score 1):

This select command will give you what you want:

```
SELECT CarID, A, COUNT(*) as c FROM TableName GROUP BY CarID, A
```

The resulting table from query will look like smthing like this:

```
CarID       A         C
------------------------
BMW        BUY        2
BMW        SELL       1
AUDI       BUY        1
AUDI       SELL       2
```

Answer (score 1):

It think you might want to do conditional aggregation here with a pivot:

```
SELECT
    CarID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) AS BUY,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A = 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS SELL
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CarID;
```

This option gives you two dedicated columns for the buy and sell counts, each of which could even be zero, depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from table
group by cardid, columnA
```